# Is it possible to set smarty directories in a derived constructor?

Tags: php, smarty, config, derived-class

Hey, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<?php
class MySmarty extends Smarty {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $smartyRoot = '/home/smarty/';

        parent::setTemplateDir($smartyRoot. "/templates/");
        parent::setCompileDir($smartyRoot."/templates_c/");
        parent::setCacheDir($smartyRoot."/cache/");
        parent::setConfigDir($smartyRoot."/configs/");
    }
}

$smarty = new MySmarty();
$smarty->display("index.tpl");
?>
```

But it fails with a `SmartyException("Unable to load template file")`. From `smarty_internal_template.php` line 163, which looks like it checks for the existence of `$this` before doing any display.

My system seems to be set up correctly, since the suggested way of doing it (calling `$smarty->set*Dir($smartyRoot.'foo');` works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the problem is from that code? I use in all my apps code like this:

```
class MySmarty extends Smarty {

 function __construct() {
    global $path, $template_dir, $production;


    parent::__construct(); 

    $this->template_dir = $template_dir;
    $this->compile_dir = "$template_dir/tpl_c";
    $this->config_dir = "$template_dir/configs";
    $this->cache_dir = "$template_dir/cache";
(...)
```

Comment: Huh. No I'm not completely sure, I just thought I had eliminated all my other options. Doing what you did actually works (ie `$this->*_dir = 'foo';` instead of `$this->setFooDir();` That's a little odd.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$this` even in context of the constructor. So try:

```
    $this->setTemplateDir($smartyRoot. "/templates/");
    $this->setCompileDir($smartyRoot."/templates_c/");
    $this->setCacheDir($smartyRoot."/cache/");
    $this->setConfigDir($smartyRoot."/configs/");
```

Should work.

Comment: That's actually how I started, and it totally didn't work. Even though I agree it should. One big problem that I ran into was that $this->setTemplateDir(''); turned $template_dir into an Array for some reason. Pretty sure that's not supposed to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The template dir can be an array, and it might internally do that. There is also addTemplateDir(). Smarty will traverse them in order. Using $this-> is the correct approach for the constructor.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That definitely makes sense, I just thought that there was some sort of bug because of the fact that copy/pasted code wasn't working.